# How to sed lines that contain only given form?

Tags: bash

This is the input:

```
asdfZE3033141xycf
asdfINSFRHxycf
```

and I need this output:

```
asdfZE3033141

asdfINSFRHxycf
```

So I used a:

```
echo -e 'asdfZE3033141xycf\nasdfINSFRHxycf' | sed '/asdfZE3033141xycf/ s=xycf$=\n='
```

but I need this in GENERAL. So I need to sed every:

```
asdfZE[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]xycf
```

line in a textfile. I just can't put the "[0-9]" in sed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not modify your work a little bit:

```
echo -e 'asdfZE3033141xycf\nasdfINSFRHxycf' | sed -e 's/^\(asdfZE[0-9]\{7\}\)xycf$/\1\n/'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with "[0-9]"? Why you can't put it in sed?

Use can simply use

```
sed '/asdfZE[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]xycf/s=xycf$=\n=' file
```

or even

```
sed '/asdfZE[0-9]\{7\}xycf/s=xycf$=\n=' file
```

sed support regex in search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean.

What about:

```
sed 's/^\(asdfZE[0-9]\{7\}\)xycf$/\1\
/'
```

? (backslash followed by a real newline character is the standard way to insert a newline character on the right hand side of the `s` command (as opposed to `\n`)).

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please decrypt `RHS` abbreviate?

Comment: @rush. RHS == Right Hand Side. Now expanded.